# Word for a certain type of "quiet agreement"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word which means a particular kind of feeling, of "quiet agreement".

Not being a poet, this feeling is difficult to describe in general. But I can give an example where this has occurred to me, which I think is common enough that anyone on StackExchange might be able to relate to:

> I see a comment on a picture or an answer to a question here in StackExchange. The question has a couple of answers, the best of which answers it satisfactorily.
>
> Then there is an answer with a score of -2
>    and it is very incomplete, maybe even inappropriate. But it somehow aligns with my thoughts, I want to upvote it but I'd rather it didn't gain too many points because it is after all not a good answer per SE's guidelines.

The same would go with a racy comment somewhere: I want to -- and will -- upvote it but it'd really be best if its score stays negative. In other words, I wouldn't wish a bad answer to succeed, or be utterly destroyed, but to fail gently.

Is there a word for this kind of sentiment?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is *sympathize*. To sympathize doesn't mean you think that someone *should* have done something, but you underarms show they feel and *why* they did what they did, even if you wouldn't have.

Comment: I HATE autocorrect. Hate it. "*Underarms show they feel*", really? Not "*understand how*", but "*underarms show*"? Frickin thing is ruining my cred!

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for edits. _Symphatize_ sounds good but is it perfect... I certainly wouldn't wish a bad answer to succeed, but to fail gently.

Comment: That last comment is definitely worth including in your question!

Comment: @DanBron: Rofl: _"...underarms show they feel"_.  I had to read that three times to believe what I was seeing. Why Autocorrect, why?

Comment: Thank heaven for autocorrect. I gave @Dan heaps of personal cred for giving words to that pacific, precious, ungainly sentiment that he enraptured so spherically with his praise, *you underarms show they feel.*

Comment: @TusharRaj ... and just now autocorrect changed "*can only*" to "*cannoli*". I think it's trolling me.

Comment: @TusharRaj The problem is modern smartphones have no haptic feedback, which combined with limited screen real estate, for me leads to missing the spacebar with *extreme* frequency. Autocorrect is invaluable for rescuing me from that error. But it's also that specific error which most often confuses the tool and leaves me with a paper trail of underarms and cannolis.

Comment: @DanBron: Well, inthat case, I guess you'll have to settle with the "Lester of two exiles."

Comment: @TusharRaj Hahahaha! I broke up when I got that notification!

Comment: We cannoli hope so.

Comment: One of these days, Autocorrect is going to start a war ...

Comment: I don't use autocorrect, but I'm constantly plagued with "missing M" syndrome.  Often I miss the M and hit backspace instead.  Thiseans thamany tes both the and the letter before the areissing.

Answer (score 3):

If there was a button you could click to express this sentiment, I would label it "*Nod*."  
[Nod](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nod): To lower and raise (the head) quickly in agreement or acknowledgment.  *American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language*, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company.

Comment: Mind quoting a dictionary definition of this sense of *nod*? Make sure to mention which dictionary you're quoting.

Comment: Sure thing.  [Nod](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nod) -- To lower and raise (the head) quickly in agreement or acknowledgment.  Citation: American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company.

Comment: As you wish, good sir.

Answer (score 3):

The word fitting your title (quiet agreement) would be *acquiescence*:

To *acquiesce* is

> to accept, agree, or allow something to happen by staying silent or by not arguing
>
> Source: [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiescing)

However, you seem to be looking for a concept which is less "quiet" and more "limited", "qualified", or "reserved".  I don't think there's a good single word way to express this.

Comment: +1, I read the question and scrolled down, and found - acquiesce. No need to go any further.

Answer (score 0):

The feeling of quiet agreement can well be expressed by the word, 'concomitant' where one may not be overt in expressing one's support.

Answer (score 0):

**[tacit](https://www.google.com/search?q=tacit%20definition)** may be what you are after:

> adjective
>  understood or implied without being stated.
>  "your
>   silence may be taken to mean tacit agreement"

(Google)

Answer (score 0):

If you upvote an answer or comment simply because it has a lot of downvoted, you are

- **rooting for the underdog**

However, you said you didn't want the amswer/ comment to win; just to fail more "gently". This could be called

- "softening the blow" 
  or
- "evening up the scales"

I suggest that if you like an answer (or a comment) and plan to upvote it, notify the answerer of that fact via a comment.

It is common to see "+1 for [xxx]" to point out what one especially likes about someone else's answer.  This can be taken as a mild compliment, although it does carry the connotation that [xxx] does not, in itself, constitute a complete good answer.